# How can I add additional company fields when creating a new user using Stripe with Angular and Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, angular, stripe-payments

I am working on my application with the Django backend and the Angular frontend and I am gonna use Stripe. At this point everything seems to be working properly however I have some doubts how can I automatically collect all needed information associated with chosen company to send new invoice at the beginning of each subscription month. At the moment I do everything like shown below. The problem is that in Angular the form has no additional fields like company name, address etc.
[image]
Any ideas what information I need and how can I collect them automatically (without manually update in Stripe dashboard) to be able to create a correct invoice?

Django:

```
    try:

        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email=user.email,
            source=request.data['token']
        )

    except stripe.error.CardError as e:

        try:
            decline_code = e.json_body['error']['decline_code']
        except:
            decline_code = e.json_body['error']['code']

        if decline_code in decline_status:

            return Response(
                {'error': True, 'message': decline_status[decline_code]},
                status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        else:

            return Response(
                {'error': True, 'message': 'Your card was declined.'},
                status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
            customer=customer.id,
            items=[
                {
                    'plan': 'my_plan',
                    'quantity': request.data['amount'],
                },
            ],
            # collection_method='charge_automatically',
            expand=['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using legacy Checkout there; I'd recommend you switch to the newer version of Checkout which will also allow you to create the Subscription as part of the Checkout process: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration

Comment: So I understand that it is impossible to achieve this with the current version and the only solution except migrating to the newer version of Checkout is to do this as it is done in the example above and then just by collecting all needed information from the user by self-written form in Angular and then sending and updating information associated with the customer in my Django backend (I mean adding company name, address fields etc.)?

Comment: There is a way to collect billing address with legacy Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout#integration-options-billing-address

Comment: I did everything on my own as I described in the comment above and everything seems to be working properly. The question is whether it is crucial and essential to switch legacy Checkout to the newer version of Checkout or if everything works well I can stay with the current version and there is no need to do migration? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can't really answer that for you - but if you need 3D Secure / SCA, you will need to migrate; if not, you can maybe wait, but you'll need to eventually since I suspect SCA will become more common.